# Vim does not spellcheck the content of <title> element in my DocBook files

Tags: spell-checking, filetype-xml

I have initiated online spell checking in `.vimrc` with

```
autocmd FileType docbk set spell spelllang=en
autocmd FileType docbk highlight SpellBad cterm=underline ctermfg=red ctermbg=none
```

in my plugin's `after/syntax/` directory, i created `docbk.vim` file with the following content:

```
    syntax spell toplevel
```

to prevent spellchecking XML markup (although i dont know what it's actually doing...).

The problem is that while everything is working fine, text inside `<title>text</title>` is not spellchecked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that spell check also doesn't work in `<emphasis>`, `<remark>`, `<comment>` and `<citation>`.

The syntax file for DocBook is rather old (2012) and I don't know if it is still maintained. Anyway you should try to contact the maintainer. See top of file `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/dockbk.vim`.

What you can do now:

Copy the file `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/docbk.vim` to your `~/.vim/syntax` (on Windows: `~/vimfile/syntax`) directory. 
Execute `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` in Vim display the value of `$VIMRUNTIME`.

Open the file and locate the lines:

```
" Add special emphasis on some regions. Thanks to Rory Hunter <roryh@dcs.ed.ac.uk> for these ideas.
syn region docbkRegion start="<emphasis>"lc=10 end="</emphasis>"me=e-11 contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity keepend
syn region docbkTitle  start="<title>"lc=7     end="</title>"me=e-8 contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity keepend
syn region docbkRemark start="<remark>"lc=8    end="</remark>"me=e-9    contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity keepend
syn region docbkRemark start="<comment>"lc=9  end="</comment>"me=e-10   contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity keepend
syn region docbkCite   start="<citation>"lc=10 end="</citation>"me=e-11 contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity keepend
```

Than add `,@spell` behind `sgmlEntity`. So this lines look like this:

```
" Add special emphasis on some regions. Thanks to Rory Hunter <roryh@dcs.ed.ac.uk> for these ideas.
syn region docbkRegion start="<emphasis>"lc=10 end="</emphasis>"me=e-11 contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity,@spell keepend
syn region docbkTitle  start="<title>"lc=7     end="</title>"me=e-8 contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity,@spell keepend
syn region docbkRemark start="<remark>"lc=8    end="</remark>"me=e-9    contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity,@spell keepend
syn region docbkRemark start="<comment>"lc=9  end="</comment>"me=e-10   contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity,@spell keepend
syn region docbkCite   start="<citation>"lc=10 end="</citation>"me=e-11 contains=xmlRegion,xmlEntity,sgmlRegion,sgmlEntity,@spell keepend
```